# Issue with background masking and react-particles-js 3.0

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, particles.js

I tried the Background Mask sample taken from [here](https://particles.matteobruni.it) in `react-particles-js` 3.0 but I cannot display anything over it.

What am I doing wrong?

You can checkout a sample here on CodeSandbox

[image: Edit try-react-particles-js-3.0]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the 'zIndex' style to bring your container to the front. Just add to your div the style:

```
  <div className="center" style={{ zIndex: "101" }}>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    I'm using react-particles-js
  </div>
```